# Gridding in Tensorflow (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

### 1) Problem Setting

Consider that you have given:

- A set of arbitrary points in the 2D plane and
- a finite grid with regular spacing.

Note that the grid and the points are not "aligned" in general.

Define a function f by placing a kernel function c with limited support at each of the points.
I want to evaluate f at each grid-point.The computational expense for evaluating c for every point on the whole grid is too large and also unnecessary, since c has finite support.

### 2) What I have tried

For each point, I created a sparse tensor storing only the support of c. These are then added in a tensorflow while loop to a dense tensor.
Even though it works, it performs poorly (cpu usage at 25% on a 4 core 3,5GHz i5). I am using python 3.5.3 and tensorflow 1.14 (cpu-version).

### 3) What my Question is

In principle, all of the mentioned sparse tensors could be calculated in parallel.

- Why is this not happening?
- Might the tensorflow while loop be the issue, since the dense tensor which accumulates all sparse tensors is a "loop_var"?
- How can I improve the performance?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

I am afraid I cannot provide a minimal working example without major effort, but below you can find the relevant piece of code:

```
# Helper function
def convolve_delta(gridsize, I, value, kernel):
    """
        DESCRIPTION:
            Evaluate the convolution of a delta peak with a kernel on a grid.

        ARGUMENTS:
            > gridsize: Size of the grid on which the convolution shall be evaluated.
            > I: The coordinate of the delta peak in the index space of the grid.
            > value: Weight of the delta peak.
            > kernel: Kernel that is used for the convolution.

            Note: The evaluation of the kernel is casted to the data type of argument "value".

        RETURNS:
            > Tensorflow operation of the gridding (sparse tensor), dtype according to value.
    """
    # Note on array indices: Arrays are indexed like a[z,y,x,...], indices/coordinates are stored as x,y,z,... .

    # Calculate the bounding box of where to evaluate the convolution
    limits = tf.map_fn(
        lambda args: tf.stack(
            (
                tf.clip_by_value(tf.cast(tf.floor(args[0] - args[1]), dtype=tf.int64), 0, args[2]), # Lower limit
                tf.clip_by_value(tf.cast(tf.ceil(args[0] + args[1] + 1.0), dtype=tf.int64), 0, args[2]) # Upper limit
            ),
            axis=0
        ),
        (I, kernel.size, tf.reverse(gridsize, axis=[-1])), # Note: "gridsize" has to be reversed (e.g. z,y,x -> x,y,z).
        dtype=tf.int64,
        parallel_iterations=1
    )
    # Note: sequence is x,y,z,... (same as I).

    # Calculate the coordinates of voxels in the box and subtract the location of the delta peak
    indices_frame = tf.stack(
        tf.meshgrid(
            *tuple(
                tf.range(tf.minimum(L[0], L[1]), L[1])
                for L in tf.unstack(limits)
            )
        ),
        axis=-1
    )
    # Note: Sequence is still x,y,z,... .

    # Convolve
    return tf.SparseTensor(
        tf.reverse(tf.reshape(indices_frame, (-1, 2)), axis=[-1]), # Note: Sequence needs to be reversed again along last axis.
        tf.reshape(tf.multiply(value, tf.cast(kernel.evaluate(tf.subtract(tf.cast(indices_frame, dtype=I.dtype), I)), dtype=value.dtype)), (-1,)), # Convolution
        gridsize
    )
#

# Kernel
def c(X):
     return tf.exp(-0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(X**2, axis=-1))
#
gridding_kernel = namedtuple("gridding_kernel", "size evaluate")
kernel = gridding_kernel(np.full(2,10), c)     

# Specification of the points we want to grid
points = tf.placeholder(...) # See function below
values = tf.placeholder(...)

# Set up the body of the tensorflow while loop
def accumulate_block(grid, points, values, blockindex, blocksize, gridsize):
    """
        DESCRIPTION:
            Convolves a block (subset) of points onto a grid.

        ARGUMENTS:
            > grid: Dense tensor with size given by argument "gridsize".
            > points: Two dimensional tensor holding the points, first index iterates through points.
            > values: One dimensional tensor holding the values corresponding to the points.
            > blockindex: Index of the block of points, points and values will
              be accessed by "points[blockindex+j, :]" and "values[blockindex+j]".
            > blocksize: Size of a block of points.
            > gridsize: Size of argument "grid".

        RETURNS:
            > grid: Block of points gridded and added to argument "grid".
    """
    # Set up while loop over block of points
    # Iteration index
    j = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
    # Sparse tensor to store the single gridded points
    gridded_block = tf.SparseTensor(tf.constant([[0, 0]], dtype=tf.int64), tf.constant([0.0], dtype=values.dtype), gridsize)
    # Iterate over block
    gridded_block, _ = tf.while_loop(
        lambda gridded_block, j: tf.less(j, blocksize), # Condition
        lambda gridded_block, j: (                      # Body
            tf.sparse.add(                      # Add to gridded block
                gridded_block,                  #
                convolve_delta(                 # Grid single point
                    gridsize,                   #
                    points[blockindex+j, :],    #
                    values[blockindex+j],       #
                    kernel                      #
                )                               #
            ),                                  #
            tf.add(j, 1)                        # Increase iteration index
        ),
        (gridded_block, j), # Specify loop variables
        parallel_iterations=1 # Does not change anything!?
    )
    # Add the gridded block to the grid and return
    grid = tf.sparse.add(grid, gridded_block)
    return grid
#

# Set up variables for the while loop over all blocks of points
i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
imax = tf.size(values)
# Where to store the gridded points
grid = tf.zeros(gridsize, dtype=values.dtype)
# Iterate
grid, _ = tf.while_loop(
    lambda grid, i: tf.less(i, imax),       # Condition
    lambda grid, i: (                       # Body
        accumulate_block(grid, points, values, i, blocksize, gridsize), # Grid block of points
        tf.add(i, blocksize)                                            # Increase iteration index
    ),
    (grid, i), # Specify loop variables
    parallel_iterations=4 # Does not change anything!?
)
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant code that you are describing? That way it will be easier for others to understand the problem.